# Raise exception from async failure in JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

When some asynchronous call within my Promise definition throws an Error, I can't seem to bubble it up to my catch handlers.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('about to fail!');
        throw new Error('async FAIL');
    }, 1000)

    throw new Error('synchronous fail!');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('catch1!!!');
    throw err;
});

promise.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('CAUGHT!');
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```

This code effectively catches the synchronous failure. But, is there any way to catch the async failure within the Promise rubric? Am I missing something fundamental about how I'm trying to use promises?

Comment: why don't you use reject?

Comment: Well, the idea is that some other call would cause the failure (not an explicit throw by me). So, I don't really want to wrap the entire block in a giant try to account for any calls that might go wrong ...

Comment: You cannot do that. "But, is there any way to catch the async failure within the Promise rubric?" --- no, it does not pop up from there since it does not belong the current call stack.

Comment: (not that a giant try/catch would even work because of the same problem of the current call stack not causing an error but an async bit throwing somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch exceptions thrown asynchronously with promises - or in any other way except the global platform error handler. Promises are not magic of course.

That's why you have to perform promisification at the lowest level possible - since promise handlers implicitly wrap calls with `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with closures if the async code has success/failure callbacks. The issue is keeping a reference to the resolve/reject functions in a different call stack:

```
function mySuccessCallback(resolve) {
    return function() {
        resolve();
    };
}
function myFailureCallback(reject) {
    return function() {
        reject();
    };
}
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var thirdPartyTool = new ThirdPartyTool();
    thirdPartyTool.executeAsync(
        mySuccessCallback(resolve),
        myFailureCallback(reject));
});
```

If there aren't success/failure callbacks then how can your code possibly know when theirs has completed an asynchronous action? unless of course your `promise` object is only promising that the async call will be executed, and nothing more, then it doesn't matter when the async action finishes. But the only way to tell if another bit of code has thrown an exception is to use the global error handler (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), because as another person said it's bubbling up in a totally different call stack. But even then how can you generically guarantee that the error being caught is caused by that particular async call and not another?